# Using contains on a String in Java

Tags: java, contains

I have a string called trips. In this string there are 3 values chosen by the enemy player.
I want the buttons which equals one of those values to change their color.

```
for(int i = 0; i <=Lobby.baanlengte;i++){
    if ((trips.contains(Speler1[i].getActionCommand()))) {
         System.out.println("Trips bevat"+i);              
         Speler1[i].setBackground(Color.gray);
    }
}
```

Say the string trips is `3,11,14`, I want the buttons 3, 11 and 14 to change their color. These buttons actually change but 1 and 4 also change since these numbers are in 11 and 14, which is not what I want.

If anyone knows how to solve this, I would appreciate that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should first [`split`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) the input string using the delimiter `,`, then compare each part using a `.equals` comparison.

Comment: I've been struggling with these answers for a while now. I have split the String, but how do I compare each part of that string?

Comment: You only need a small change to your code. If you have called the split thing `parts`, then add a loop from `0` to `parts.length` between the `for` you have and the `if`, and replace `trips.contains` with `parts[index].equals` or something like that.

Comment: Sorry but I've added this between the first for-loop, for (int b = 0; b <= parts.length; b++) {
                    if ((parts[b].equals(Speler1[i].getActionCommand()))) {
                        System.out.println("Trips bevat" + i);
                        Speler1[i].setBackground(Color.gray);
                    }
                }
But now I get this, AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 3

Comment: Pinpoint the line that is causing this by looking at the exception, and figure out why you're out of bounds. Your top loop is suspicious because it is bound by `Lobby.baanlengte` but indexes `Speler1` - might not be the problem, but it is suspicious.

Comment: Sorry for all these questions, you help is very appreciated. 

            String parts[] = trips.split(",");
            System.out.println(parts);

The print line prints, [Ljava.lang.String;@1e4457d.. Is this what it is supposed to print or is this where the problem is?

Answer (score 2):

Don't use a String as a container of other Strings. Use a [`java.util.Set<String>`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Set.html):

```
Set<String> trips = new HashSet<String>();

// ...

if (trips.contains(Speler1[i].getActionCommand())) {
    System.out.println("Trips bevat"+i);              
    Speler1[i].setBackground(Color.gray);
}
```

This will have additional advantages:

- it will avoid duplicates in the set of players
- it will allow you to add and remove players from the set easily

Note: variables in Java should always start with a lower-case letter.

Answer (score 0):

Split the string up to array

see documentation: http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)

```
String trips_array[] = trips.split(",");
for(int i = 0; i < trips_array.length; i++){
    Speler1[i].setBackground(Color.gray);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved this. The String had some blank spaces. After replacing them with nothing everything worked as it should work. Thanks for the help :)

String trips is for example [ 13, 14, 16].

```
trips = trips.replace("[", " ");
trips = trips.replace("]", " ");
trips = trips.replace(" ", "");
String parts[] = trips.split(",");

for(int i = 0; i <= Lobby.baanlengte; i++){
    for (String item : parts){
        if(item.equals(Speler1[i].getActionCommand())){
            Speler1[i].setBackground(Color.gray);
        }
    }
}
```